# Problem with gpg and apt-get update - missing keys?

Tags: debian, apt, gpg

I do not know how, but I managed to mess up apt-get.
Executing

```
sudo su
apt-get update
```

I get errors like the following

```
W: http://security.debian.org/dists/stretch/updates/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
W: GPG error: http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9D6D8F6BC857C906 NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553
W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
```

for the repositories:

```
http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-proposed-updates InRelease
http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
```

I understand that there are some keys missing and I tried to create them with

```
gpg --keyserver keyring.debian.org --recv-keys 8B48AD6246925553
```

but as a reply I got

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Additionally I have another problem with http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main Translation-en:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/i18n/Translation-en  BZ2_bzread: /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_stretch_main_i18n_Translation-en.bz2 Read error (-5: DATA_ERROR_MAGIC)
```

which seems to have to do with the Zip-format!? No idea what I did.

Any ideas/hints how to fix my two problems?

Cheers, Christian

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to fix this is to manually download [the `debian-archive-keyring` package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/debian-archive-keyring/download) and install that, then run `apt update` again. You’ll also need to restore the permissions on `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg`:

```
sudo chmod 444 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg
```

The `Translations` problem is a bad file on the servers, there’s nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I downloaded the debian-archive-keyring package and installed it with sudo dpkg -i debian-archive-keyring_2017.5_all.deb, but apt update shows the same mistake:

W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-proposed-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010

Comment: Oh, I missed the permission error, see my update.

Comment: I did this, but the error persists. The size of my trusted.gpg is only 32 bytes, so I believe it is empty. If I do apt-key list I do not see any keys. Also the directory trusted.gpg.d is empty ? Any idea how to restore this?

Comment: Re-installing `debian-archive-keyring` is supposed to restore the contents of the `trusted.gpg.d` directory.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but in either way doing sudo apt-get install --reinstall debian-archive-keyring or via dpkg from the downloaded deb-file, the directory /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d stays empty. Apt-get lets me reinstall the debian-archive-keyring, but warns that the package cannot be authenticated.

Comment: If you run `dpkg-deb -c /path/to/debian-archive-keyring_2017.5_all.deb` you should see that the package does indeed ship those files. What does `ls -ld /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` output? Do you have any `path-exclude` directives in `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg` or files in `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95071/discussion-between-christian-lomp-and-stephen-kitt).